# Duplicate Predispatch event. What throwexception to use?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, validation

I've successfully created a Predispatch event to test some logic before you 'duplicate' a product in Magento. 
However, I'm trying to stop the event, but continue on the same screen so the event could be fixed.

What I get right now is a white screen with the triggered messages.

[image]

Here is my testing code that works.

```
$productId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$name = $product->getName();
if($name == 1)
{

Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Duplication Validation Testing Error Message'));
}
```

This throwException works on prevalidation before save, but not here. I have also tried, but it still fires the 'duplicate event' and then displays the error. I need a throwException like the pre validation of product save.

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Test'));
```

Comment: Although not the answer to this particular questions. You can use the product_duplicate event to achieve the same type of validation and use the throwException listed above. Magento makes it very hard to find the answers the these questions.